# VM Options missing for Maven Project

Tags: maven, netbeans, project-properties, netbeans-8

Can someone tell me where I can find the *VM Options* settings in the *Run* page of the *Project Properties*?[image]

According to the help pages it should be right there. It is a Maven based project which might be the case that the setting is missing. If that's the case, could you please tell me how to define VM options for such projects?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run panel differs based on packaging. Your project is apparently one of the j2ee packagings, which have the Run panel related to deployment. If you want to modify how Run Main Class is executed, please check the Actions panel.

(Run with VM Options only appears for jar projects)

Comment: Thanks. So to pass system properties (like with the -D switch) it should be enough to add them to the _Set Properties_ list of the action? Like for example `targetPlatform=DEV`? Somehow they're not picked up by the app like it used to work in IntelliJ. I keep trying.

Comment: right, if you invoke that actions aferwards. You can watch what's being executed at the start of your maven build being run. If -DtargetPlatform=DEV is printed out, it was sent to the maven JVM. If not, you might have edited different action than you are editing. Please note that properties can be also set in "Configurations" tab. When the given configuration is activated, then all executions and even the IDE project loading are using the property.